# How to allow users to access some routes publicly with VueJS Router/SPA

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, vue-router, laravel-api

I'm currently building a new web application with **VueJS SPA**, **VueJS Router**, and **Laravel**, users should be able to access pages as guests (non-authenticated) or logged-in (authenticated)!

I include `$this->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);` for the SpaController to limit access to my pages to authenticated users only but some of pages (routes) should be publicly accessible as well but be part of SPA.

How could I make `/:username`, `/:username/places` routes publicly accessible? Using `beforeEach` when user is logged-off still redirects to a `/login` page, looks like `$this->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);` doesn't allow to reach the `/:username/places` route!

`routes.js`:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

import Cities from './views/Cities';
import Places from './views/Places';
import Home from './views/Home';
import Dashboard from './views/Dashboard';
import NotFound from './views/NotFound';

let routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: Home,
        meta: {    requiresAuth: true   },
    },
    {
        path: '/404',
        name: '404',
        component: NotFound,
        meta: {    requiresAuth: false   },
    },
    {
        path: '/:username',
        name: 'dashboard',
        component: Dashboard,
        meta: {    requiresAuth: false   },
        children: [
            {
                path: 'places',
                name: 'places',
                component: Places,
                meta: {    requiresAuth: false   },
            },
        ]
    },
    {
         path: 'cities',
         name: 'cities',
         component: Cities,
         meta: {    requiresAuth: true   },
    },
    {
        path: '*',
        redirect: '/404'
    },
];

const router = new VueRouter ({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
       next('/test')
    } else next()
})

export default router
```

`web.php`:

```
Route::get('logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('/auth/redirect/{provider}', 'Socialite\SocialController@redirect');
Route::get('/callback/{provider}', 'Socialite\SocialController@callback');

Route::get('/{any}', 'SpaController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

`SpaController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class SpaController extends Controller
{
    // This class and its' functions are available only for authorised and verified users
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
    }


    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('spa');
    }
}
```

`spa.blade.php`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    @include('layouts.header')
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app" class="content">
        @include ('layouts.nav')

        <main class="py-4">
            <div class="container">
                <app></app>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
    @include('layouts.footer')
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use `vue-router` [beforeEach navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards). This would be called before any of your vue routes is accessed. You can combine that with [route meta fields](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html) where you could specify which routes require authentications. Of course, you need to track somewhere if the user is logged in or not

Comment: This is just [one example](https://scotch.io/tutorials/vue-authentication-and-route-handling-using-vue-router). It's showing node as backend, so you can skip the first part

Comment: @ljubadr, thanks for your reply...in order to use navigation guard, should I comment (remove) ```$this->middleware('auth')``` from the SpaController then, because otherwise when a user is logged out and trying to reach any route it will redirect them to the ```/login``` page?

Comment: `$this->middleware('auth')` is in laravel. You want your backend to always validate if the user is logged in. Do not remove that middleware call or you could have users access restricted resources without being logged in

Comment: Also, if user tries to access restricted page it's ok to redirect them to login page. Laravel by default should redirect the user back to that same page after login.

Comment: @ljubadr could you please have a loot at my edited post, not sure what I'm doing wrong but I still can't reach particular route when user is logged off, it keeps redirecting to a ```/login``` page!

Comment: Could you post your related laravel routes? How are you initially loading the page that has vue SPA app? Also, did you define the routes in laravel for `/:username` and `/:username/places`?

Comment: @ljubadr, please have a look at my updated post!

Comment: I see that you have catch all route `Route::get('/{any}', 'SpaController@index')->where('any', '.*');` that will load your vue SPA, but it has `auth` middleware. That means that you will always get redirected to `login` page if your are not authorized. You would need to remove that `auth` middleware and to allow your vue SPA to always load.

Comment: You can make an ajax call before you call your `new Vue()`. Fetch the info about the user (null if not logged in, or some data if he's logged in). That way you would have the information if user is logged in, and you can use that in your `beforeEach` route... Something [like this](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/solved-ajax-calls-before-bootstrapping-app-with-vuex-best-practices/16392/4)

Comment: @ljubadr by removing the ```$this->middleware(['auth', 'verified']); ``` middleware from the ```SpaController``` I'm having a different problem - after registration user gets redirected to the ```home``` page rather than to `email/verify` page until user confirms an email! Now sure how will I be able to make it work using **VueRouter**?

Comment: @ljubadr also using just front-ends **VueRouter** middleware (guard) will it be secure enough?

Answer (score 0):

That can be done from your `laravel` `route`

Inside your `routes>api.php` file,

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function(){
 // contains the api controllers to be accessed when user is logged in
}

//list of routes to be accessed publicly goes here, e.g.
Route::get('/userworkexperience/{user}', 'ControllerName@method')->name('something.else');
```

I hope this helps